# Solving an exponential equation in like terms

Tags: exponential-function

This one may be fairly easy, yet, for the life of me, I can't remember how to do it.

I would like to solve this equation to express `x` in terms of `n`:

$$2^n-2^{(n-1)}=24x$$

I stumbled upon this equation in the shower yesterday morning. I've always liked the number 24, for no apparent reason really, and always claimed it to be my favorite number. Over the years, I've begun to find its significance in various different ways.

Comment: $$24x=2^{n-1}(2-1)\implies x=\frac{2^{n-1-3}}3$$

Comment: you just need to divide both sides by 24 to have x as the subject.

Comment: do you mean $2^n-2^{n-1}=24\cdot x$?

Comment: Thanks @labbhattacharjee thats what I was looking for.